How can I fix that transactions of my old wallet show up as unconfirmed upon loading the wallet?
I am trying to load my old Bitcoin Qt 0.8.6 wallet and I am left with old transactions as unconfirmed. How do I fix this problem? The balance in the wallet is not confirmed by the network.

This question is similar to: How do I securely update Bitcoin Core?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. You should backup wallet.dat first and you will have to wait for the wallet software to synchronise with the network

Can you describe in more detail how you went about recovering your old wallet? What software did you use to import the wallet? If it is a fresh install of Bitcoin Core, has it finished synchronizing?
